# Scala - Using 'this' keyword multiple times one after the other will fail

Tags: scala, this

I've come across an issue where using the `this` keyword in Scala multiple times within the same method will actually fail.

I cannot replicate the problem here because the codebase is too large, but I will do my best to show the problem.

I have a class, Foo, with an override-able method fooMethod. Inside fooMethod, three property values are generated, and the current class instance is updated with these properties separately, using `this`. However, only the last `this` call actually sets any of the properties, the two preceding `this` calls have no effect on the object.

```
case class Foo(prop1: prop, prop2: prop2, prop3:prop3) extends FooParent {

    override def fooMethod(){
        val propA = gen()
        val propB = gen()
        val propC = gen()

        this.withPropA(propA)
        this.withPropB(propB)
        this.withPropC(propC)
    }

    def withPropA(:propA): Foo = this.copy(prop1 = propA)
    def withPropB(:propB): Foo = this.copy(prop2 = propB)
    def withPropC(:propC): Foo = this.copy(prop3 = propC)

}
```

The above code will only apply the final `this.withPropC` call, and therefore only prop3 is updated.

However, if I do the following

```
case class Foo(prop1: prop, prop2: prop2, prop3:prop3) extends FooParent {

    override def fooMethod(){
        val propA = gen()
        val propB = gen()
        val propC = gen()

        // here
        val one = this.withPropA(propA)
        val two = one.withPropB(propB)
        two.withPropC(propC)
    }

    def withPropA(:propA): Foo = this.copy(prop1 = propA)
    def withPropB(:propB): Foo = this.copy(prop2 = propB)
    def withPropC(:propC): Foo = this.copy(prop3 = propC)

}
```

then all of the properties are updated. Why is this?

Comment: There is a misunderstand of immutability and `copy` utility along that

Comment: Each call of the  `copy` method creates a new instance of `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Case class are immutable, so `copy` based functions (like those `withProp*`) never mutate `this`.

Moreover, in case of sequential property changes, each update must be applied on the result of previous one (chain); Not on (orginal) `this`, what would create separate instances corresponding to each unrelated update.

If you really intend to use such functions, it should be

```
withPropA(propA). // chain update
  withPropB(propB). // chain
  withPropC(propC)
```

What can be written:

```
copy(prop1 = propA, prop2 = propB, prop3 = propC)
```

Comment: So I have tried the first method you proposed but it wouldn't work. In other classes, doing the same process but chaining only two property updates seems to work, but in this case for three, it doesn't.  I understand this may require way more information about the class itself, but unfortunately I cannot provide that.